# Problems for a Homotopy excursion in HoTT

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lo.logic, homotopy-theory, homotopy-type-theory

I would like to know some open problems in HoTT for Homotopy theorist (without knowledge of logic). With such a Homotopy theorist I mean someone who takes a serious reading ("at the level") of Cisinski's [Univalent universes for elegant models of Homotopy types](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.0058).

Comment: Asking merely for a list of open problems seems the wrong approach if one wants to actually understand the mathematics...

Comment: If someone just drops a bunch of open problems on your head that won't be very useful. I'd recommend joining the [HoTT list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/homotopytypetheory) and having an informed discussion. I am sure the crowd will be very welcoming to a homotopy theorist who wants to get into HoTT.

Comment: Given @AndrejBauer's comment, would you like to clarify a bit more what actual research background you have in homotopy theory?

Answer (score 3):

The introduction of the HoTT book ends with an "Open problems" section that certainly answers your question.

Comment: Also https://ncatlab.org/homotopytypetheory/show/open+problems